# Marshal XMLAttribute in derived class

Tags: xml, jaxb, superclass, derived-class

I want to marshall a XMLAttribute in derived class, but I have some problem.

I have 2 derived class and 1 super class, as following:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
}

@XmlSeeAlso({Dog.class, Cat.class})
public class Animal {

}

@XmlRootElement(name="some_element_wrapper")
public SomeElementWrapper() {

    List<Animal> listAnimal;

    @XmlElement(name = "animals")
    public List<Animal> getListAnimal() {}
    public void setListAnimal(List<Animal> listAnimal) {}
}
```

Suppose I have a List populated with some data.
I want to generate XML from my classes like this :

```
<some_element_wrapper>
    <animals>
        <animal type="dog">....</animal>
        <animal type="cat">....</animal>
    </animals>
</some_element_wrapper>
```

My issue is that i get what I want except the type attribute. I tried with other different solutions, moving attribute type in super class, or overriding derived type field, but with no result.
Please, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make `JAXBContext` Aware of Subclasses**

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation isn't automatically aware of a mapped classes subclasses.  You will either need to include them in the array of classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext` or use an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on one of the mapped classes.

```java
@XmlSeeAlso(Dog.class, Cat.class)
public class Animal {

}
```

**Inheritance Indicator**

If you are looking to use the type attribute to specify the subtype being used, I would recommend not doing that and using the `xsi:type` attribute instead which is how inheritance is represented in an XML (with XML an XML schema) and the default representation in JAXB.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

If you really don't want to use an `xsi:type` attribute, you could leverage an `XmlAdapter` to use a `type` attribute as the inheritance indicator.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) also offers an extension (`@XmlDescrinatorNode`/`@XmlDescrimatorValue`) that makes this use case easier (I'm the MOXy lead).

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html

Comment: Thanks @Blaise. I got it with Eclipse JAXB (MOXy)...it is more useful and practical. I updated my question with your right notes.